# Percentage of polygon at, or less than, specific height supplied by raster

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon

I am using QGIS to process some LIDAR data. I need to be able to define the area of a pond with respect to its depth (i.e it is 100m^2 at 32mAOD and 500m^2 at 33mAOD).

Is there a way of finding the percentage (or area) of a polygon with its height at less than or equal to a specified value (the height being supplied from the LIDAR raster)?

Answer (score 1):

Have achieved this the long way by creating rasters at spacing of 25 cm over the area, and then using the zonal statistics tool to extract the number of cells at a certain height inside a given polygon. Combined with the LIDAR info. the areas are then easy to calculate.